# can aws greengrass stream manager be triggered from a server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

I am trying to figure out a solution where an edge device (raspberry pi) that doesnt have a static ip, should stream video to kinesis stream when the user triggers.

My approach is host(which can be accessed from the edge device) a fastapi that takes user input and stores the state, the edge device constantly checks if there is an user-input and will send video stream as per the stage stored in fastapi.

Instead of having this edge device pining the fastapi server every few seconds,can i use aws green grass to solve this ?

AWS green grass already has a IoT stream manager, that can send the data to kinesis stream, all i need to know is if its possible to turn on/off this stream manager based on user request, user will start the stream by sending a request to fastapi and that should somehow trigger the greengrass stream manager. Is it possible ?

Note : continuous streaming is not an option, we need trigger based streaming.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using [AWS IoT Shadow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-shadows.html).

From the AWS Cloud, you could write data to IoT shadow and this new shadow update can be picked up by Greengrass and generate an event into [your custom component](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v2/developerguide/interact-with-shadows-in-components.html) that would enable (or disable) the streaming.